# :import command inside Scala REPL

Tags: scala

It's said in the book *Scala in Action* that using **:import** command inside Scala REPL we will see:

```
scala> :imports 
    1) import java.lang._       (153 types, 158 terms)
    2) import scala._           (798 types, 806 terms)
    3) import scala.Predef._    (16 types, 167 terms, 96 are implicit)
```

And according to this book those packages above are all **automatically** imported. But in my REPL (Scala 2.10.2) it returns only one line:

```
scala> :imports
     1) import scala.Predef._   (162 terms, 78 are implicit)
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: which version of Scala is used in the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Scala in Action" was written for 2.9:

```
:~$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :imports
 1) import java.lang._             (193 types, 199 terms)
 2) import scala._                 (798 types, 804 terms)
 3) import scala.Predef._          (16 types, 167 terms, 96 are implicit)
```

Comment: Thanks alatar. But in the ebook I got, it's 2.10.0. The author: "I’m running Scala version 2.10.0, and all the code examples should work for this version and above."

Comment: @Pauli i think this answer is correct, cause on the manning page it's written that the book was updated for 2.10, but at first it was written under 2.9. And the repl listing wasn't updated for 2.10. Cause this output is really only on 2.9